# How to embed VEGA on streamlit using components?

Tags: javascript, streamlit, vega

I'm currently trying to use VEGA in Streamlit by using streamlit components. However, I'm facing some issues as the plot is not appearing as expected.

I followed the Streamlit tutorials and the examples for the streamlit-vega-lite component, but it seems that the component is outdated.
In my case plot is only displayed when I manually rerun Streamlit. I've also tried using st.experimental_rerun but it didn't work, and even pressing F5 to refresh the page doesn't solve the problem.
Do you have any advice or suggestions on how to resolve this issue? I'd greatly appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks!

My **init**.py:

```
import os
import streamlit.components.v1 as components

_RELEASE = False


if not _RELEASE:
    _component_func = components.declare_component(
        "vega",
        url="http://localhost:3001",
    )
else:
    parent_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    build_dir = os.path.join(parent_dir, "frontend-react/build")
    _component_func = components.declare_component("my_component", path=build_dir)


def vega_component(spec={}, key=None, **kwargs):

    return _component_func(spec=spec, **kwargs, key=key, default={})

if not _RELEASE:
    import streamlit as st
    import pandas as pd
    import json

    st.subheader("Test Vega Barplot")

    with st.sidebar:
      st.title('Teste')
      teste  = st.file_uploader('Insert Scout output')
    if teste is not None:
      teste = { "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
                  "width": 400,
                  "height": 200,
                  "padding": 5,
                  "data": [
                    {
                      "name": "table",
                      "values": [
                        {"category": "A", "amount": 28},
                        {"category": "B", "amount": 55},
                        {"category": "C", "amount": 43},
                        {"category": "D", "amount": 91},
                        {"category": "E", "amount": 81},
                        {"category": "F", "amount": 53},
                        {"category": "G", "amount": 19},
                        {"category": "H", "amount": 87}
                      ]
                    }
                  ],

                  "signals": [
                    {
                      "name": "tooltip",
                      "value": {},
                      "on": [
                        {"events": "rect:mouseover", "update": "datum"},
                        {"events": "rect:mouseout",  "update": "{}"}
                      ]
                    }
                  ],

                  "scales": [
                    {
                      "name": "xscale",
                      "type": "band",
                      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "category"},
                      "range": "width",
                      "padding": 0.05,
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "yscale",
                      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "amount"},
                      "range": "height"
                    }
                  ],

                  "axes": [
                    { "orient": "bottom", "scale": "xscale" },
                    { "orient": "left", "scale": "yscale" }
                  ],

                  "marks": [
                    {
                      "type": "rect",
                      "from": {"data":"table"},
                      "encode": {
                        "enter": {
                          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "category"},
                          "width": {"scale": "xscale", "band": 1},
                          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "amount"},
                          "y2": {"scale": "yscale", "value": 0}
                        },
                        "update": {
                          "fill": {"value": "steelblue"}
                        },
                        "hover": {
                          "fill": {"value": "red"}
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "text",
                      "encode": {
                        "enter": {
                          "align": {"value": "center"},
                          "baseline": {"value": "bottom"},
                          "fill": {"value": "#333"}
                        },
                        "update": {
                          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "signal": "tooltip.category", "band": 0.5},
                          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "signal": "tooltip.amount", "offset": -2},
                          "text": {"signal": "tooltip.amount"},
                          "fillOpacity": [
                            {"test": "isNaN(tooltip.amount)", "value": 0},
                            {"value": 1}
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
              }
      
      vega_component(spec=teste)
```

My JS file:

```
import {
  Streamlit,
  StreamlitComponentBase,
  withStreamlitConnection,
} from "streamlit-component-lib"
import React, {ReactNode} from "react"
import {Vega} from "react-vega";



class VegaScope extends StreamlitComponentBase {
  public render(): ReactNode {
    var spec = this.props.args["spec"]
    return (
      <Vega
      spec={spec}
    />
      )
  }

}


export default withStreamlitConnection(VegaScope)
```

Comment: Can you share what component you're using? Is it [this one](https://github.com/domoritz/streamlit-vega-lite)? Streamlit does support displaying Vega Lite charts natively via [`st.vega_lite_chart`](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/charts/st.vega_lite_chart)  – I'd recommend using that over the custom component